# Disappearing Composite on resize

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have two Composites. The first one works fine. I do a resize on the Composite and it behaves correctly. I am doing the same thing on the 2nd Composite but it disappears. Maybe something inside the Composite is causing this behavior?

Code:

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {
    parent.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    final Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    composite.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
            composite.setSize(parent.getSize());
        }
    });
    composite.setLayoutData(new RowData(622, 34));
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));

    Label lblPolicy = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
    lblPolicy.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
    lblPolicy.setText("Policy:");

    text = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);
    GridData gd_text = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1);
    gd_text.widthHint = 566;
    text.setLayoutData(gd_text);

    Label lblNewLabel = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
    lblNewLabel.setText("X");

    final Composite composite_1 = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    //FIXME THIS RESIZE CAUSES EVERYTHING IN THE COMPOSITE TO DISAPPEAR
    composite_1.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
            composite_1.setSize(parent.getSize());
        }
    });
    composite_1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    composite_1.setLayoutData(new RowData(624, 166));

    Group grpGrid = new Group(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
    grpGrid.setText("Grid");
    GridData gd_grpGrid = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1);
    gd_grpGrid.widthHint = 180;
    gd_grpGrid.heightHint = 109;
    grpGrid.setLayoutData(gd_grpGrid);

    Label lblSegment = new Label(grpGrid, SWT.NONE);
    lblSegment.setText("Segment:");

    Label lblLifecycle = new Label(grpGrid, SWT.NONE);
    lblLifecycle.setText("Lifecycle:");

    Combo combo = new Combo(grpGrid, SWT.NONE);

    Combo combo_1 = new Combo(grpGrid, SWT.NONE);

    Group grpStore = new Group(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
    grpStore.setText("Store");
    GridData gd_grpStore = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1);
    gd_grpStore.heightHint = 110;
    gd_grpStore.widthHint = 201;
    grpStore.setLayoutData(gd_grpStore);

    Label lblServer = new Label(grpStore, SWT.NONE);
    lblServer.setText("Server:");

    Combo combo_2 = new Combo(grpStore, SWT.NONE);

    Label lblNumber = new Label(grpStore, SWT.NONE);
    lblNumber.setText("Number:");

    text_1 = new Text(grpStore, SWT.BORDER);
    new Label(composite_1, SWT.NONE);

    Button btnSubmit = new Button(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
    btnSubmit.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
    btnSubmit.setText("Submit");
}
```

I have tried taking out the setBounds for each element in the Composite. This did not work.

Comment: Don't mix `setBounds` with Layouts - the layout will override the bounds.

Comment: Yes - I have fully removed any instance of setBounds. However, nothing is appearing.

Comment: @greg-449 I added the entire method. setBounds no longer included.